# Prevent blurring of PDF images when inserted into a word document

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, images, adobe-illustrator

I have a very large word document with many images to be inserted into it. I created the images in illustrator and the only export format that produced clear enough images was PDF. TIFF or JPEG at 300ppi were blurry when zoomed in. However, when I insert the PDF into my word document it becomes blurry. I have turned off image compression and this still occurs. Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: PDF is not a pixel based image, but a vector graphic. Blurring therefore occurs in word itself.

Comment: Did you take the time to [use a search engine to find a solution by yourself?](https://www.google.com/search?q=word+pdf+blurry)

Comment: Is .wmf an export option for you? You can insert those directly into Word, like any png, jpeg, etc., and it's a vector-based format.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert a PDF page as an object in Office, you will get a poorly rendered raster graphic. I recommend to insert it as a vector graphic:

Starting with Office 2016 and [Microsoft 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-svg-images-in-microsoft-365-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c), Microsoft Office finally supports Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG). So you can convert your PDF to SVGs and insert them into your Office document.

You can use [`pdf2svg`](https://cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/) to convert your (multi-page) PDF into (multiple) SVGs:

```
pdf2svg input.pdf output_%d.svg all
```

Comment: The key here is to insert as a picture (Insert / Pictures / This Device), and not an object (Insert / Object / Create from file), the latter doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can tick this box in excel-options-advanced
[image]

Comment: Excel? The question was in regards to Word.

Answer (score 0):

How about considering not inserting the PDF into your Word document but instead either:

PDF the Word document and combine it to the existing PDF; or

Create a PDF Portfolio which allows you to combine documents while retaining the existing document format(s) - no matter which format they are - into one PDF 'package' (called a "PDF Portfolio").